# JSON Error Parsing Identical Data - Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json

We have a webservice that is used to work with our third-party services. One of those is SmartyStreets, which is used to validate US Addresses. Here is my issue: randomly, there is a JSON parsing error. Resubmitting the address seems to work fine. I can't find no specific thing that indicates the issue. Below is the URL:

```
https://us-street.api.smartystreets.com/street-address?auth-id=xxxxx&auth-token=xxxxx&street=4952+W+STRONG+ST++CHICAGO+IL+60630-2420&candidates=10
```

Nothing special, right?

Here is the response:

```
{"input_index":0,"candidate_index":0,"delivery_line_1":"4952 W Strong St","last_line":"Chicago IL 60630-2420","delivery_point_barcode":"606302420520","components":{"primary_number":"4952","street_predirection":"W","street_name":"Strong","street_suffix":"St","city_name":"Chicago","state_abbreviation":"IL","zipcode":"60630","plus4_code":"2420","delivery_point":"52","delivery_point_check_digit":"0"},"metadata":{"record_type":"S","zip_type":"Standard","county_fips":"17031","county_name":"Cook","carrier_route":"C021","congressional_district":"05","rdi":"Residential","elot_sequence":"0079","elot_sort":"A","latitude":41.97079,"longitude":-87.75191,"precision":"Zip9","time_zone":"Central","utc_offset":-6,"dst":true},"analysis":{"dpv_match_code":"Y","dpv_footnotes":"AABB","dpv_cmra":"N","dpv_vacant":"N","active":"Y"}}
```

That response had an error (and yes, I know, no [], I purposely take them out). Below is an identical response made a few seconds later:

```
{"input_index":0,"candidate_index":0,"delivery_line_1":"4952 W Strong St","last_line":"Chicago IL 60630-2420","delivery_point_barcode":"606302420520","components":{"primary_number":"4952","street_predirection":"W","street_name":"Strong","street_suffix":"St","city_name":"Chicago","state_abbreviation":"IL","zipcode":"60630","plus4_code":"2420","delivery_point":"52","delivery_point_check_digit":"0"},"metadata":{"record_type":"S","zip_type":"Standard","county_fips":"17031","county_name":"Cook","carrier_route":"C021","congressional_district":"05","rdi":"Residential","elot_sequence":"0079","elot_sort":"A","latitude":41.97079,"longitude":-87.75191,"precision":"Zip9","time_zone":"Central","utc_offset":-6,"dst":true},"analysis":{"dpv_match_code":"Y","dpv_footnotes":"AABB","dpv_cmra":"N","dpv_vacant":"N","active":"Y"}}
```

The response above did not have an error and worked fine. The error from the first one is below:

```
-+Exception:
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException
-+Message:
Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: }. Path '', line 1, position 820.
-+Stack Trace:
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(String json, JsonLoadSettings settings)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(String json)
at POS.Backend.Services.Providers.SmartyStreetsProvider.ValidateAddress_2622(String addressToValidate, EntityType entityType, Nullable`1 entityID, String entityName, Int32 storeID, Int32 tellerID) in C:\Users\Wayen\Documents\Projects\GIT\dPoint\Backend\Providers\SmartyStreetsProvider.cs:line 128
```

Can anyone see a difference? I can't. I have absolutely no idea why the first has an error and the second does not.

Here is the code where the error occurs:

```
List<SmartyStreetsAPIResponseAddressResult> foundAddresses = new List<SmartyStreetsAPIResponseAddressResult>();

            jsonResponse = jsonResponse.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");  //remove the extra [ ] at the start & end
            string[] candidates = jsonResponse.Split(new string[] { "},{" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            foreach (string candidate in candidates)
            {
                //the split can remove parts of the JSON return value. Restore these parts
                string correctedCandidateJSONValue = candidate;
                if (correctedCandidateJSONValue.Substring(correctedCandidateJSONValue.Length - 2, 2) != "}\n" )
                    correctedCandidateJSONValue += "}";

                if (correctedCandidateJSONValue.Substring(0, 1) != "{")
                    correctedCandidateJSONValue = correctedCandidateJSONValue.Insert(0, "{");

                JObject addressData = JObject.Parse(correctedCandidateJSONValue);
```

The error occurs on the JObject.Parse(correctedCandidateJSONValue) line. Randomly. By the way, this just started a week ago; there have been no code changes in nearly a year.

Sometimes the JSON does come back with an additional tag, such as "footnotes"

```
 {"input_index":0,"candidate_index":0,"delivery_line_1":"900 S Clark St","last_line":"Chicago IL 60605-3679","delivery_point_barcode":"606053679990","components":{"primary_number":"900","street_predirection":"S","street_name":"Clark","street_suffix":"St","city_name":"Chicago","state_abbreviation":"IL","zipcode":"60605","plus4_code":"3679","delivery_point":"99","delivery_point_check_digit":"0"},"metadata":{"record_type":"H","zip_type":"Standard","county_fips":"17031","county_name":"Cook","carrier_route":"C025","congressional_district":"07","building_default_indicator":"Y","rdi":"Residential","elot_sequence":"0454","elot_sort":"A","latitude":41.87051,"longitude":-87.63065,"precision":"Zip9","time_zone":"Central","utc_offset":-6,"dst":true},"analysis":{"dpv_match_code":"D","dpv_footnotes":"AAN1","dpv_cmra":"N","dpv_vacant":"N","active":"Y","footnotes":"H#"}}
```

It's been fixed, thanks to dbc. My updated code is below:

```
            JsonSerializerSettings serializeSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { CheckAdditionalContent = false };
            object deserializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResponse, serializeSettings);

            foreach (JObject candidate in (JArray)(deserializedJson))
            {
                //get only the address parts we need, which is the two lines (free-form) + the number, direction, name, suffix, city, state abbr, and zip code, along with PO BOX info if available
                JToken lineOne = candidate.SelectToken("delivery_line_1");
                JToken lineTwo = candidate.SelectToken("last_line");

                JToken houseNumber = candidate.SelectToken("components.primary_number");
                JToken directionToken = candidate.SelectToken("components.street_predirection");
                JToken streetName = candidate.SelectToken("components.street_name");
                JToken streetSuffix = candidate.SelectToken("components.street_suffix");
                JToken city = candidate.SelectToken("components.city_name");
                JToken state = candidate.SelectToken("components.state_abbreviation");
                JToken zipCode = candidate.SelectToken("components.zipcode");

                bool isPOBox = false;

                if (lineOne.ToString().ToLower().Contains("po box"))
                {
                    isPOBox = true;
                }

                JToken county = candidate.SelectToken("metadata.county_name");
                foundAddresses.Add(new SmartyStreetsAPIResponseAddressResult((lineOne != null ? lineOne.ToString() : string.Empty),
                    (lineTwo != null ? lineTwo.ToString() : string.Empty),
                    (houseNumber != null ? houseNumber.ToString() : string.Empty),
                    (directionToken != null ? directionToken.ToString() : string.Empty),
                    (streetName != null ? streetName.ToString() : string.Empty),
                    (streetSuffix != null ? streetSuffix.ToString() : string.Empty),
                    (city != null ? city.ToString() : string.Empty),
                    (state != null ? state.ToString() : string.Empty),
                    (zipCode != null ? zipCode.ToString() : string.Empty),
                    (county != null ? county.ToString() : string.Empty),
                    isPOBox));
            }
```

Like I said in my comment, I'm new to JSON. Instead of reading up on how it works, I took a look at the string returned from the service and tried to parse it myself. I split it by brackets and iterated through that rather than deserializing it with the right settings. The updated code works great now. Thanks dbc!

Comment: I ran them both in https://jsonlint.com/ and they are both valid JSON. The error could be somewhere else

Comment: Did you try trimming the response? Maybe providing the snippet of where you are capturing and parsing the response might help point to the error

Comment: Possibly the server is sporadically appending a nonprintable character to the end of the JSON?  Try deserializing to a `JObject` after explicitly setting [`JsonSerializerSettings.CheckAdditionalContent = false`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_CheckAdditionalContent.htm)

Comment: Oh, the problem is probably that the line `jsonResponse.Split(new string[] { "},{" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` is splitting in the middle of a candidate in a specific case, because the server is now including some extra data that breaks your splitting logic.  This is beginning to look like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).  Can you share a raw `jsonResponse` before you do any string manipulations?

Comment: Thanks - tomorrow I will check out both suggestions and let you know!

Comment: This is probably my fault, completely. I'm new to JSON. I've never used it prior to this third-party service; I had never even heard of it.

What I did was I used a string split to break apart candidates from the raw JSON, then removed brackets, then tried to parse it using the Parse method. What I should have done was de-serialize it (with settings), then iterate through the enumerable collection, then parse those (as needed) for the pieces of the addresses. That seems to be working better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per dbc, answer is below:

```
            JsonSerializerSettings serializeSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { CheckAdditionalContent = false };
            object deserializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResponse, serializeSettings);

            foreach (JObject candidate in (JArray)(deserializedJson))
            {
                //get only the address parts we need, which is the two lines (free-form) + the number, direction, name, suffix, city, state abbr, and zip code, along with PO BOX info if available
                JToken lineOne = candidate.SelectToken("delivery_line_1");
                JToken lineTwo = candidate.SelectToken("last_line");

                JToken houseNumber = candidate.SelectToken("components.primary_number");
                JToken directionToken = candidate.SelectToken("components.street_predirection");
                JToken streetName = candidate.SelectToken("components.street_name");
                JToken streetSuffix = candidate.SelectToken("components.street_suffix");
                JToken city = candidate.SelectToken("components.city_name");
                JToken state = candidate.SelectToken("components.state_abbreviation");
                JToken zipCode = candidate.SelectToken("components.zipcode");

                bool isPOBox = false;

                if (lineOne.ToString().ToLower().Contains("po box"))
                {
                    isPOBox = true;
                }

                JToken county = candidate.SelectToken("metadata.county_name");
                foundAddresses.Add(new SmartyStreetsAPIResponseAddressResult((lineOne != null ? lineOne.ToString() : string.Empty),
                    (lineTwo != null ? lineTwo.ToString() : string.Empty),
                    (houseNumber != null ? houseNumber.ToString() : string.Empty),
                    (directionToken != null ? directionToken.ToString() : string.Empty),
                    (streetName != null ? streetName.ToString() : string.Empty),
                    (streetSuffix != null ? streetSuffix.ToString() : string.Empty),
                    (city != null ? city.ToString() : string.Empty),
                    (state != null ? state.ToString() : string.Empty),
                    (zipCode != null ? zipCode.ToString() : string.Empty),
                    (county != null ? county.ToString() : string.Empty),
                    isPOBox));
            }
```